# Floating Point comparison specific

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I have a specific question about floating point comparisons. I know that it's not recommended to use the == comparison due to precision issues, but in this specific case, I am wondering if, in all cases / compilers, this statement will hold true?

```
float a = 1.02f;
float b = 1.02f;

if(a == b)
{
   print(true);
}
else
{
   print(false);
}
```

In other words, if I assign floating point numbers exactly, with no addition, subtraction, demotion, or promotion, will this always hold true?

Comment: Yes, your code verbatim should print true.

Comment: probably, but can you guarantee that they will never have any arithmetic done with them? I would compare them with epsilon and a degree of error allowed. floating point numbers are a bit strange if you don't understand how they are encoded.

Comment: @QuinnRoundy I guarantee that I will not have any arithmetic ops. I'm really just trying to see if floating points are viable to be used as keys in an if else block; this is just a base case / sanity check.

Comment: @Zinusoidal Not all things are compared simply with (a == b) Check out this for ways to compare floats: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler should consistently translate floating point constants that are identical to the same value - if not, it's a bug in the compiler [which of course is not impossible]. However, as soon as you do ANYTHING ELSE to the value (such as reading it from a file including `cin`) or do simple math (add 1.0, then subtract 1.0), the value is not guaranteed to be the same any longer.

As pointed out, the value "Not A Number" or "NaN" is guaranteed to NEVER be equal to anything, and all comparisons except `!=` will be `false`, no matter what it is compared to - this is part of the specification for floating point. But all other constants, as long as you are JUST using a constant to assign to a variable, it should remain the same throughout the code.

Of course, you can't rely on TWO DIFFERENT compilers coming up with the same exact value from the same source-code [many times they will, but sometimes they simply will do some different rounding of the last bit, or something like that which causes differences]

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that (provided you're on a IEEE 754 system) if you do the *same* operations to two values, they will still compare the same. i.e. `((1+1)/3)==((1+1)/3)`. That's because (unless you're using ffast-math), the computer is required to round correctly to the least-significant-bit for all individual operations. In fact, that means that you can even expect `((1+1)/3)==((2+2)/6)`. But ((1+1.1)/3) may not be equal to an equivalent ((2+2.2)/6), because rounding can occur during the `+` *and* `/` in that case.

Comment: "... NaN" is guaranteed to NEVER be equal to anything" ... "all comparisons except `!=` will be false ..."  +1